# How to find entropy of Depth images in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, kinect, entropy

I want to compute depth entropy of a depth image in Matlab (same as this [work](https://research.iiitd.edu.in/groups/iab/PID2857163.pdf) ). Unfortunately, the authors don't reply my emails. There is a function,*"entropyfilt"*, that compute the local entropy of grayscale image. I've used this function with a depth input image that captured by Kinect but it hasn't worked probably. Here is my input depth image:

[image]

Here is the code used for entropy computing:

```
J = entropyfilt(Depth);
imshow(mat2gray(J))
```

Sorry, My "reputation view" isn't enough, so I can't upload my result image.

How can I compute entropy image of a depth image? I want to acquire an image same as figure 4 in above paper.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even with low reputation you should be [able to upload an image](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) to stack.imgur.com and link to it. Embedding it is apparently not possible but could easily be done by someone else later on.

Answer (score 1):

It is written in the paper, for each pixel you first extract two patches from the image, then you calculate the entropy of each patch. The formula for which is also in the paper and well-known in statistics.

If you want to use the function `entropyfilt`, you need to provide as a second argument a mask image that describes the patch (all pixels within the patch need to be 1 in the mask, others need to be 0). This is detailed in the documentation of said function.

The authors generate one color image from two entropy images. How they do so they seemingly forgot to mention.

I think the paper is low quality.

Answer (score 0):

```
image1= imread('where is located ')
entropy(image1)
imshow(image1)
```